# Showing a text if request takes longer than 1 sec in redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I want to show a text if the `yield call()` takes longer than 1000ms. I tried `setTimeout()` as I usually use, but that doesn't work and I don't see the problem. Here is the code block for it:

```
let t = setTimeout(
 yield put(
   setLoaderMessage(
     'The requested report data is being loaded, this may take some time.'
   )
 ), 1000);

const responseData = yield call(
 "My api call",
 "payload"
);

yield put(setoaderMessage(''))
clearTimeout(t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `delay` effect. E.g. something like this:

```js
const messageTask = yield fork(function*() {
  yield delay(1000)
  yield put(setLoaderMessage('some message'))
})

const responseData = yield call('My api call', 'payload');

yield cancel(messageTask)
yield put(setLoaderMessage(''))
```